# PHP Variable declaration not working in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following code in a Laravel 5.4 Blade view:

```
@php($strVal = $character->Strength)

                        @php($strMod = 0)

                        <?php 
                            if ($strVal == 10 || 11) {
                                $strMod = 0;
                            } elseif ($strVal == 12 || 13) {
                                $strMod = 1;
                            } elseif ($strVal == 14) {
                                $strMod = 2;
                            } else {
                                $strMod = 2;
                            }


                        ?>
```

It takes data from a MySQL table. 
$strVal is an int from the table. The code creates a var called $strMod and goes through a number of if/elseif statements to see what it will be equal to.

It's shown on a webpage as follows:

```
<div class="huge charMod">+{{$strMod}}</div>
```

My issue is that it displays as "+0" no matter what strVar equals. strVar is working fine, I can pull it from the DB and display it via {{ $strVal }} but strMod refuses to take a value other than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your if checks to

```
if ($strVal == 10 || $strVal == 11) {
    $strMod = 0;
} elseif ($strVal == 12 || $strVal == 13) {
    $strMod = 1;
} elseif ($strVal == 14) {
    $strMod = 2;
} else {
    $strMod = 2;
}
```

`if ($strVal == 10 || 11)` will always return true. If you want to check two values you need to specify that by using the variable == value again as in the example above.

Comment: You, sir, are a wizard. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`$strVal == 10 || 11` will always return true

Because that's not how comparisons work in PHP. The `==` operator has a higher precedence than `||` operator, so it will be performed first.

It means that `$strVal == 10 || 11` gets turned into `false || 11` .. which is `true`.

Instead of that code, I would recommend:

```
$map = [
    10 => 0,
    11 => 0,
    12 => 1,
    13 => 1, 
    // you dont actually need 14, because default value is aready 2
];

$result = 2;

if (array_key_exists($strVal, $map)) {
    $result = $map[$strVal];
}

$strVal = $result;
```

Or, **if you are using PHP 7.0+** it all can actually be written as:

```
$map = [10 => 0, 11 => 0, 12 => 1, 13 => 1];
$strVal = $map[$strVal] ?? 2;
```